# How to remove/set JTextArea border in JTable cell in Nimbus look and feel

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtextarea, nimbus

Edit: I have added a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) code

I have extended JTextArea in TableCellRenderer because I wanted to achieve the Multiline text wrapping [Mentioned in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16597431/how-to-implement-multiple-line-text-renderer-in-jtable) and that is working fine. Now I have ran into weird problem with Nimbus look and feel. Nimbus is adding a border with every cell as shown in the below picture. [image]

My Class:

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;

public class TestJTableMultiline extends JFrame {
  /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public TestJTableMultiline() {
    super("Multi-Line Cell Example");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    DefaultTableModel dm = new DefaultTableModel() {
      /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public Class<String> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        return String.class;
      }
      public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
        return false;
      }
    };
    dm.setDataVector(
        new Object[][]{
            {"A0, Line1\nA0, Line2\nA0, Line3", 
             "B0, Line1\nB0, Line2", 
             "C0, Line1"}, 
            {"A1, Line1", 
             "B1, Line1\nB1, Line2", 
             "C1, Line1"},
            {"A2, Line1", 
             "B2, Line1", 
             "C2, Line1"}
            }, 
            new Object[] {"A", "B", "C"});

    JTable table = new JTable(dm);
    table.setDefaultRenderer(String.class, new MultiLineTableCellRenderer());
    TableRowSorter<? extends TableModel> sort = new TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel>(dm);
    table.setRowSorter(sort);
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
    getContentPane().add(scroll);
    setLocationByPlatform(true);
    setSize(400, 430);
    setVisible(true);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      try{
            for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    System.out.println("choosed nimbus");
                    break;
                }
            }
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    TestJTableMultiline frame = new TestJTableMultiline();   
    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
      public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        System.exit(0);
      }
    });
  }
}

class MultiLineTableCellRenderer extends JTextArea 
implements TableCellRenderer {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private List<List<Integer>> rowColHeight = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();

public MultiLineTableCellRenderer() {
  setLineWrap(true);
  setWrapStyleWord(true);
  setOpaque(true);
}

@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
    JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
    int row, int column) {
  if (isSelected) {
    setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
    setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
  } else {
    setForeground(table.getForeground());
    setBackground(table.getBackground());
  }
  setFont(table.getFont());
  if (hasFocus) {
    setBorder(UIManager.getBorder("Table.focusCellHighlightBorder"));
    if (table.isCellEditable(row, column)) {
      setForeground(UIManager.getColor("Table.focusCellForeground"));
      setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Table.focusCellBackground"));
    }
  } else {
    setBorder(new EmptyBorder(1, 2, 1, 2));
  }
  if (value != null) {
    setText(value.toString());
  } else {
    setText("");
  }
  adjustRowHeight(table, row, column);
  return this;
}

/**
 * Calculate the new preferred height for a given row, and sets the height on the table.
 */
private void adjustRowHeight(JTable table, int row, int column) {
  //The trick to get this to work properly is to set the width of the column to the 
  //textarea. The reason for this is that getPreferredSize(), without a width tries 
  //to place all the text in one line. By setting the size with the with of the column, 
  //getPreferredSize() returnes the proper height which the row should have in
  //order to make room for the text.
  int cWidth = table.getTableHeader().getColumnModel().getColumn(column).getWidth();
  setSize(new Dimension(cWidth, 1000));
  int prefH = getPreferredSize().height;
  while (rowColHeight.size() <= row) {
    rowColHeight.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(column));
  }
  List<Integer> colHeights = rowColHeight.get(row);
  while (colHeights.size() <= column) {
    colHeights.add(0);
  }
  colHeights.set(column, prefH);
  int maxH = prefH;
  for (Integer colHeight : colHeights) {
    if (colHeight > maxH) {
      maxH = colHeight;
    }
  }
  if (table.getRowHeight(row) != maxH) {
    table.setRowHeight(row, maxH);
  }
}

}
```

`What has been tried:`

1. I have tried `setBorder(null)` and `setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black))` and various other color like forground and background color of the table.
2. Then I looked at [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12844337/nimbus-jtextarea-default-border) question and tried that solution as well but I am not able to resolve the border problem. I have also tried removing setBorder call altogether but the results are same.
3. I have also tried removing the cell border in jtable mentioned in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167112/remove-cells-border-in-a-jtable) question

How can I resolve this border problem with Nimbus look and feel.

Note: I am getting nice view with other look and feel.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson it is here at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16597431/how-to-implement-multiple-line-text-renderer-in-jtable

Comment: isn't there JScrollPane, if yes then to remove/or Borders for JTextArea in JScrollPane and from JScrollPane too

Comment: @mKorbel no there is no JScrollPane except the one which is the container of JTable

Comment: @AndrewThompson I have added the SSCCE code now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- This might work in JDK 1.7.0 or later:

  ```
  MultiLineTableCellRenderer r = new MultiLineTableCellRenderer();
  UIDefaults d = new UIDefaults();
  d.put("TextArea.borderPainter", new Painter() {
    @Override public void paint(Graphics2D g, Object o, int w, int h) {}
  });
  r.putClientProperty("Nimbus.Overrides", d);
  r.putClientProperty("Nimbus.Overrides.InheritDefaults", false);

  table.setDefaultRenderer(String.class, r);
  ```

[image]

SSCCE

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo;

public class TestJTableMultiline2 {
  public JComponent makeUI() {
    String[] columnNames = {"A", "B", "C"};
    Object[][] data = {
      {"A0, Line1\nA0, Line2\nA0, Line3", "B0, Line1\nB0, Line2", "C0, Line1"},
      {"A1, Line1", "B1, Line1\nB1, Line2", "C1, Line1"},
      {"A2, Line1", "B2, Line1", "C2, Line1"}
    };
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames) {
      @Override public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
        return String.class;
      }
      @Override public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
        return false;
      }
    };
    JTable table = new JTable(model);
    table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);

    MultiLineTableCellRenderer r = new MultiLineTableCellRenderer();
    UIDefaults d = new UIDefaults();
    d.put("TextArea.borderPainter", new Painter() {
      @Override public void paint(Graphics2D g, Object o, int w, int h) {}
    });
    r.putClientProperty("Nimbus.Overrides", d);
    r.putClientProperty("Nimbus.Overrides.InheritDefaults", false);

    table.setDefaultRenderer(String.class, r);
    return new JScrollPane(table);
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override public void run() {
        createAndShowGUI();
      }
    });
  }
  public static void createAndShowGUI() {
    try {
      for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
        if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
          UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
          break;
        }
      }
    } catch(Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Multi-Line Cell Example 2");
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.getContentPane().add(new TestJTableMultiline2().makeUI());
    f.setSize(320, 240);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
  }
}

class MultiLineTableCellRenderer extends JTextArea implements TableCellRenderer {
  private List<List<Integer>> rowColHeight = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
  //private Border fhb = UIManager.getBorder("Table.focusCellHighlightBorder");
  //private Border epb = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(2,5,2,5);
  public MultiLineTableCellRenderer() {
    super();
    setLineWrap(true);
    setWrapStyleWord(true);
    setOpaque(true);
    //System.out.println(fhb.getBorderInsets(this));
    //setBorder(epb);
  }
  @Override
  public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
    JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
    boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
    setFont(table.getFont());
    setText(value != null ? value.toString() : "");
    setMargin(new Insets(2,5,2,5));
    //setBorder(hasFocus ? fhb : epb);
    if (isSelected) {
      setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
      setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
    } else {
      setForeground(table.getForeground());
      setBackground(table.getBackground());
    }
    adjustRowHeight(table, row, column);
    return this;
  }

  /**
   * Calculate the new preferred height for a given row, and sets the height on the table.
   * http://blog.botunge.dk/post/2009/10/09/JTable-multiline-cell-renderer.aspx
   */
  private void adjustRowHeight(JTable table, int row, int column) {
    //The trick to get this to work properly is to set the width of the column to the
    //textarea. The reason for this is that getPreferredSize(), without a width tries
    //to place all the text in one line. By setting the size with the with of the column,
    //getPreferredSize() returnes the proper height which the row should have in
    //order to make room for the text.
    //int cWidth = table.getTableHeader().getColumnModel().getColumn(column).getWidth();
    int cWidth = table.getCellRect(row, column, false).width; //Ignore IntercellSpacing
    setSize(new Dimension(cWidth, 1000));
    int prefH = getPreferredSize().height;
    while (rowColHeight.size() <= row) {
      rowColHeight.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(column));
    }
    List<Integer> colHeights = rowColHeight.get(row);
    while (colHeights.size() <= column) {
      colHeights.add(0);
    }
    colHeights.set(column, prefH);
    int maxH = prefH;
    for (Integer colHeight : colHeights) {
      if (colHeight > maxH) {
        maxH = colHeight;
      }
    }
    if (table.getRowHeight(row) != maxH) {
      table.setRowHeight(row, maxH);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 but why bothering with calculating for PreferredSize, I think that doLayout() do it that as good as get (maybe my lazyness)

Comment: @mKorbel thanks. ``doLayout()`` maybe easier than above way. Would you show me a link to your post? (Not sure I have seen your post to use ``doLayout()``, but I lost a link)

Comment: [doLayout()](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A714968+[jtable]+doLayout%28%29), (tag) + (tag) ... + methods/String in thread, reason for massive tags edits here by (kleopatra) & (Andrew Thompson) and my person, otherwise isn't possible to searching here confortly

Comment: @mKorbel Thanks for a useful reference :)